# Trimming an array (filled via DBI)

Tags: sql-server, perl, arrays, dbi

I'm trying to read data from SQL Server database using Perl and the DBI module. My intention is to read the data and print it into a text file (comma separated). When I do this, I get the result like this:

```
var1,var2,var3
40406,20 ,783
50230,78 ,680
50230,78 ,680
50230,78 ,680
50230,78 ,680
```

So there is a whitespace between the second variable data and the comma. I tried to trim this using the code below, but it did not work. How should I modify my code to get rid of those whitespaces?

My code is here:

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

sub trim;

my $dbs = "dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER={xxxx}";
my ($username, $password) = ('un', 'pwd');

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbs, $username, $password)
               or die "Can't connect to $dbs: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select var1, var2, var3 from db.dbo.table")
                or die "Can't prepare statement: $DBI::errstr";

$sth->execute();

my $outfile = 'temp.txt';
open OUTFILE, '>', $outfile or die "Unable to open $outfile: $!";

print OUTFILE join(",", @{$sth->{NAME}}), "\n";

while (my @re = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   print OUTFILE join(",", trim(@re)), "\n";
}

close OUTFILE;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

############## subroutines ##################
sub trim($) {
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You're new so I'll tell you the standard SO etiquette: 1.- Upvote and accept answers, especially if they are what you wanted (downvote bad answers) 2.- Modify your question instead of adding answers, this is not a forum. Glad it worked!

Comment: Echoing Vinko, I am going to suggest that you accept his answer and delete the non-answers you posted as answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your trim() function does not modify the list in place (nor it handles a list).

So, in real TIMTOWTDI fashion, you should either modify the function to return a new array:

```
sub trimArray {
    my @arr = @_;
    my @rv;
    for my $val (@arr) {
        $val =~ s/^\s+//;
        $val =~ s/\s+$//;
        push @rv, $val;
    }
    return @rv;
}

#and then

print OUTFILE join(",", trimArray(@re)), "\n";
```

or pass a reference to your function and then modify the array in place

```
sub trimInPlace {
    my $arrRef = shift;
    for my $val (@$arrRef) {
        $val =~ s/^\s+//;
        $val =~ s/\s+$//;
    }
}

#and then

trimInPlace(\@re); #Note the \
print OUTFILE join(",", @re), "\n";
```

or use map

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

#... the same

while (my @re = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   print OUTFILE join(",", map { trim($_); } @re), "\n"; #Applies
                                                         #trim() to each element
}

#...

############## subroutines ##################
sub trim { #Don't use prototypes
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

or try using chomp, by modifying $/, which will only remove a trailing space, nothing more.

```
#!/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;

#... the same

my $old_sep = $/;
$/ = " ";
while (my @re = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
   chomp(@re); #Modifies in place, returning number of changes
   print OUTFILE join(",", @re), "\n";
}
$/ = $old_sep;
```

Comment: trimInPlace didn't work from some reason (didn't have time to check why). The array inside the function is trimmed, but outside is unaffected. trimArray works well.

Comment: trimInPlace is working on local copy `@arr`, should be acting on `@$arrRef` : `… my $arrRef = shift; for my $val (@$arrRef) { $val =~ s/\s+$//; }`

Answer (score 1):

You could also check to see if DBD::ODBC supports the ChopBlanks attribute:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dbs, $username, $password, { ChopBlanks => 1 } )
```

the ChopBlanks attribute trims the trailing whitespace of any CHAR fields (that is if your driver supports it ... I'm not sure if DBD::ODBC does).

Comment: DBD::ODBC does support ChopBlanks so long as the column is a char. If it does not work please send me an example and I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Why does that field have trailing whitespace? Usually that points to some sort of problem with the database model. Besides your `trim()` function, you might investigate why the data is dirty.

Comment: char(N) columns in MS SQL Server are returned as N characters even if you only inserted N-M characters. If you don't want that you use varchar columns.